# Configure maven lifecycle mapping for native plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Hi i try to use lwjgl library, and in my project pom.xml use configuration to copy dependencies. In eclipse Indigo and older maven plugin all works fine. Bud now with eclipse luna and new maven plugin i must write lifecycle mapping for that plugin. But im not able to do so. Can you halp me, how to write this.

pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpacknatives</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <!--suppress MavenModelInspection (this line is for IDEA)-->
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Error that eclipse says

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.googlecode.mavennatives:maven-nativedependencies-plugin:0.0.6:copy (execution: unpacknatives, phase: generate-resources)
```

With my lifecycle mapping xml im traing something like this

```
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpacknatives</goal>
                </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <ignore />
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
    </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

But if i tray anything nothing is happen. Of course i reload my mapping. Please help me with this. Thanks Pavel

I expect answer which work for multiple programators with minimal work, not setting library to project, not copy debendencies to some directory ... Maven should handle it itself with my nexus repo.

Comment: Where have you located the lifecylce mapping file?

Comment: In my workspace as reguler xml file (versioned in mercurial). Loading to maven options with absolute path

Comment: I don't wanted to know if you have it in your workspace i would like to know the specific path and name of the file.

Comment: c:\Workspace\MORPHEUS\morpheus\tools\eclipse\lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml